# SQL de-duplication of flight path combinations: Same Origin + '-' + Destination & Destination + '-' + Origin must be treated as duplicate

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates, concatenation

I'm trying to figure out how to crack this requirement. Here is the Flight table

| Origin | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| LAX | PDX |
| NYC | SEA |
| PDX | LAX |
| SEA | NYC |

I need to group the data on LAX-PDX route with PDX-LAX route (no preference to which Origin or Destination is first in the string) and same for the data associated with SEA-NYC and NYC-SEA routes. Can you help me figure out how to treat those routes that the Origin and Destination are swapped as duplicates so I can do a GROUP BY on single route (No preference on which route survives as long as the outcome is either LAX-PDX or PDX-LAX)?

Comment: You can take the alphabetically smaller one as the origin, and the other as destination, both in the select and in the group by

Comment: Select case when origin < destination then origin else destination as origin, ...

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of a desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would group by the concatenation logic

```
select case when origin> destination then 
            concat(origin,'-',destination)
            else 
            concat(destination,'-',origin)
        end as grp_col
       ,count(*) as no_of_routes
   from table
group by case when origin> destination then 
            concat(origin,'-',destination)
            else 
            concat(destination,'-',origin)
        end
having count(*)>1
```